# Select prices the last 5 rows of the table and only shows the rows that has the same value

Tags: mysql

i would like to know how could i get the last 5 rows and only show the prices that has the same value.

Here is an example of my Table

ID prices is unique it has a primary key and has auto increment.

```
IDPRICES | PRICES 
39       | 500
38       | 300 
37       | 100 
36       | 200 
35       | 500
```

**now i only want to show the values from rows 35 and 39 because these are the only 2 prices that has the same values.**

Here is an example of my Query

```
select idprices, prices from test.prices
order by idprices desc
limit 5;
```

Comment: Let's improve this question. Especially the part about the last 5 and same value.

Comment: i.e. 39|500
      35|500
i only want to Show the rows 39 and 35 since they have the same prices

Comment: so 2 that have 39|500 are shown if no 35|500 ? See how bad and vague the question is

Comment: do i need two queries on this one? first off i want to get the last 5 rows of my table. second is i only want to show the rows that has the same prices? in my example table up there its 39 and 35 that has the same prices so i only want to show the rows 39 and 35.

Comment: what is the id, unique? what is last? You need to improve your question writing. And you didn't answer my question I just asked anyway.

Comment: yes the id is unique sorry it has a primary key. so the last one in the table is id 39. and it auto increments everytime i insert another price.

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery to get the last 5 rows, then use `GROUP BY` to look for duplicates.

```
SELECT prices, GROUP_CONCAT(idprices) idprices
FROM (SELECT idprices, prices
      FROM test.prices
      ORDER BY idprices DESC
      LIMIT 5) x
GROUP BY prices
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/07507/3)

Comment: Thank you. this is the last code i tried but it still shows the other values that has the same value. 
SELECT *

FROM test.prices

WHERE prices IN
 
   (    
 SELECT prices
        
  FROM test.prices
        
  GROUP BY prices
          
HAVING COUNT(prices) > 2
 
 
    )

ORDER BY idprices desc
limit 5
;

Comment: I've added `GROUP_CONCAT(idprices)` so you can get the IDs of all the rows in the duplicate.

Comment: This is kind of overkill, isn't it?

Comment: @Strawberry I got the impression he wanted the IDs of the rows that were matched, so I added them this way.

Comment: I'm still not convinced that the question is clear enough to say what the OP wants, so perhaps your impression is valid.

Comment: Thank you so much @Barmar this is what im looking for sorry if i dont know how to ask this question.